# Serializable decorator instead of SelectList in view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, decorator

I'm storing `ViewModel` in session.
There is a problem with live environment. Because of configuration, I can't store non serializable classes in session and `SelectList` not marked as `Serializable`.

What is the better way to exclude usage of `SelectList` in `ViewModel` as a `DataSource` for `DropDown` controls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store in your view model the collection of items, not the select list.
Then, add a method to your ViewModel called `GetSelectList()` that creates a SelectList using the collection.

That way, you store the data, and once you retrieve that object from session, you can call the `GetSelectList()` method to use it in the dropdownlist.

You could even pass a parameter to set the selected value.